# Reload Office content Add-In from powerpoint #24

Tags: vsto, office-js, office-addins

I have office web add-in added in my PowerPoint slides (multiple instances of add-in). Need some settings that will be common across all add-in instances. for that tried to use VSTO Add-In and save those in settings file of it.
Now the issue is how i can pass those settings to each content add-in instances so i can read those in each add-in instance.
OR
Is there a way where i can get handle of content add-in's context menu buttons 'Reload', so after any change from VSTO Add-In, can i just call 'Reload'. I can move settings in DB if needed.

[Content Add-In Reload option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Yohu.png)

Appreciate any insights on this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store these externally. Settings are scoped to a single Add-in (technically to a single manifest id). From the [documentation](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/settings):

> The settings created by using the methods of the  Settings object are saved per add-in and per document. That is, they are available only to the add-in that created them, and only from the document in which they are saved.

Comment: that's right. but i have multiple instances added to powerpoint of same add-In, in that case all have same manifest id.

Comment: You stated you were using both VSTO and Web Add-ins. There is no mechanism for communicating between these, which is why you'd need to store settings externally.

Comment: Okay, got it. Is there a way i can get handle on 'Reload' option of add-In Menu